# Webbrowser rendering complete event

Tags: wpf, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, browser, internet-explorer-10

I am developing an app that loads local language content into wp8 webbrowser from html files stored in isolated storage. I show a loading icon when i do and browser.Navigate method whihc calls the local html. I am using javascript to notify my code when the document load completes.
This is handled in script_notify and this is where i hide the loading icon. My problem is that the page takes some time to render on the screen and there is no loading icon to tell the user that document is still being loaded(user doesn't know that rendering is happening).

I tried window.onpaint event but that seems to be not supported.

Could anyone tell me a way to handle the above case. Thanking you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried with [LoadCompleted event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.controls.webbrowser.loadcompleted(v=vs.105).aspx)?

Comment: I did try LoadCompleted event. It gets called before Script_Notify. And it doesn't tell me that that page has rendered.

Comment: I am running into a similar situation with a Win 7 WPF application. The LoadCompleted event only tells you that the content has finished downloading. I am looking for something that tells me the content has been rendered, and I can't see any events for this.